# Flutter Provider is not showing data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider, flutter-provider

iam learning flutter state management with providers my senior told, so I am creating a commentpageui almost similar like Instagram, inside that I need to show some data from api, actually I am getting the data and printed inside console, but I am trying show in app by wrapping with consumer widget but data is not showing, I will attach the entry point where changenotifier is provided,

the data is getting called during init() method, printing value insider provider class, also I created a button calling the method insider provider class also, but not showing ,please help me

Entrypoint of coomentpage

```
class CommentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  CommentPage({super.key});

  //List widgets = [Topsection()]; // list of widgtes in page

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return
     Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider<CommentPageProvider>(create: (context) =>CommentPageProvider() ,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(children: [
              Topsection(),
             
             
MiddleSection(likeCount: 11, commentCount: 90),
             
    
             
              BottomSection(
                likeCount: 12,
                hourCount: 1,
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ;
  }
}
```

provider class

```
class CommentPageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  //CommentDataState commentDataState = CommentDataState.isNotLoaded;
  static CommentPageProvider instance = CommentPageProvider();

  // bool ispreesed = false;

  List<LikeModelData> data = [];

  bool isLoading = false;

  getLikesData() async {
    isLoading = true;
    //commentDataState = CommentDataState.isLoading;
    notifyListeners();

    data = (await LikeServiceCall().getdata());

    print("PROVIDER $data");

    print(data[1].postId);
    //commentDataState = CommentDataState.isLoaded;

  //  isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Ui section

```
class MiddleSection extends StatefulWidget {
  MiddleSection(
      {super.key, required this.likeCount, required this.commentCount});

  final int likeCount;
  final int commentCount;

  @override
  State<MiddleSection> createState() => _MiddleSectionState();
}

class _MiddleSectionState extends State<MiddleSection> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    CommentPageProvider.instance.getLikesData();
    //  getdata();
  }

  getdata() async {
    likesdata = await CommentPageProvider.instance.getLikesData();

    print(likesdata[0].userId);

    // likesdata = await LikeServiceCall().getdata();
  }

  bool isLikebuttonPressed = false;
  List<LikeModelData> likesdata = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //final likedData = Provider.of<CommentPageProvider>(context);

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CommentPageProvider>(
      create: (context) => CommentPageProvider(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: SizedBox(
            child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<CommentPageProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .getLikesData();
                },
              ),

              Consumer<CommentPageProvider>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 80,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: value.data.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        LikeModelData likeModelData = value.data[index];

                        print("mydata${likeModelData.favStatus}");
                        return Text(
                          likeModelData.postId.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
```

Comment: provider is a state management. you only need to create it 1 times. remove `return ChangeNotifierProvider......` . just use `return Padding....`

Comment: Did you register you provider in main.dart??

Comment: actually I don't have access to main.dart file, that's why I am confused, instead of main function they told to provide entry point in commentpage(the page which I am creating),then declare all providers there